# Can i use fb-prophet for multivariate time series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have dataset with below listed columns. It is monthly dataset.

- Run_date
- Actauls_Sales
- Actual_gross_profit
- Actual_Revenue

I need to forecast all 3 values over given time period(lets say for next 1 year), can i use Facebook prophet for above use case ?

Please share your valuable inputs here.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started working on multivariate time series analysis. You can use fb prophet for multivariate analysis by adding the extra features to the model with the help of add_regressor() method.

Here is the [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZhPO043lqU).